# Tool written in Go works fine from terminal (in any directory) but gives "command not found" error when called from inside a script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, golang

I wrote a shell script that bundles a few networking tools together (amass, nmap etc) and they all work fine except [httprobe](https://tzusec.com/tag/httprobe/) (a tool that takes a list of domains and probes for working http and https servers). The tool is written in `Go`. The Go Interpreter is in my $PATH. The tool works perfectly when used from the terminal (in any directory including the one the script is in). I wish I could provide more information but I'm stumped and really can't think of how to debug this.

OS: Elementary OS (Ubuntu bionic base)

Comment: How are you invoking “httprobe”? How are you invoking the script? What is the exact error message?

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for the reply, Inside the script I'm using `cat wordlist.txt | sort -u | httprobe -s -p https:443` ( to filter out http severs).  Script is run by `sudo ./script.sh <domain>` and the error `./script.sh: line : httprobe : command not found`.

Comment: I managed to fix this, turns out that go was in my $PATH but not in the secure_path at /etc/sudoers so essentially every go command that I ran with sudo would error out that means that when I ran the script with `sudo ./script.sh` would error out because one of the commands that actually ran inside the script was `sudo httprobe`. Fixed it by adding go to /etc/sudoers/secure_path

Comment: A lesson: include more information in the question. Your question doesn't even mention `sudo`. You were asked "how are you invoking the script?" and you chose to write a comment instead of editing the question. Then you answered in a comment. Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is supposed to work. Your question and comments can be rebuilt and form a [self-answered question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). The question should describe the problem without relying on comments; and the solution should be in an answer.